# Image dimensions

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code in excel that will determine the dimensions of the images from a given web link.
Below is the code I created;

```
Sub ccheck()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

Dim path As String
ie.Visible = True

path = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
ie.navigate path

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = ie.document
Dim sdd As String
Dim size As String

For i = 1 To 20
sdd = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(i).src)
size = Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(i).Width) + "x" + Trim(doc.getElementsByTagName("img")(i).Height)
Sheet2.Range("A" & i).Value = path
Sheet2.Range("B" & i).Value = sdd
Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = size
Next i

End Sub
```

But the problem is, if the height or the width attribute is not given in the website's source code the script gives the value as zero.

Is there any other way to get the image dimensions besides the method given in the code.

Kindly help with the same as I am new to vba. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is in path variable?

Comment: The path variable is the required weblink from which the dimension of the images is to be determined

Comment: Kinldy provide the weblink

Comment: It can be any desired weblink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have made some modifications to code.

```
Sub ccheck()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    Dim path As String
    ie.Visible = True

    path = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268923/image-dimensions"
    ie.navigate path

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set doc = ie.document

    Dim sdd As String
    Dim size As String

    Dim imgEle As Object
    Set imgEle = doc.getElementsByTagName("img")

    Dim i As Object, j As Long

    j = 1
    For Each i In imgEle
        sdd = Trim(i.src)
        size = Trim(i.Width) + "x" + Trim(i.Height)
        Sheet2.Range("A" & j).Value = path
        Sheet2.Range("B" & j).Value = sdd
        Sheet2.Range("C" & j).Value = size
        j = j + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I dont have a link that has image tag with no height and width attributes. So cant check for the same. 

Will the above code work if the height and the width attribute is not declared for image tag in the source code.

Comment: @user2330230 Yes it would work. Every HTMLImg object in dom has height & width property.

Comment: OK.Thanks a ton for helping me out. I have checked a couple of sites. Its working fine.